# Is it possible on Heroku to pause Delayed_jobs so it stops taking new jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I'm often releasing on Heroku an app using Delayed_Jobs. Everytime I have to wait until no more jobs are present (enqueued or working), then scale workers to 0, then deploy, then re-launch workers.

I'm always worry a new job may starts as I scale down.

Is it possible to "pause" processing of **new** jobs.

The ideal behaviour would be that Delayed_jobs finish the job it's currently processing but doesn't take any new ones. So Enqueued Jobs can be there, just no Working ones.

Ideally I'm thinking a flag in the database I can set for release, then wait until number of working jobs is 0 to do my release.